# Converting if-else statement to if-else if-else statement

Tags: if-statement, nested, boolean

How do I convert this nested `if-else` statement into a non-nested `if-else` `if-else` statement? You may need to add some boolean operators to make this completely non-nested:

```
if (ball > 0) {
    if (cup > 0) {
        console.log(“I have a ball and cup.”);
    } else {
        console.log(“I have a ball.”);
    }
} else {
    if (cup > 0) {
        console.log(“I have a cup”);
    } else {
        console.log(“I have nothing”);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, then maybe this can help:

```
if (ball > 0 && cup > 0) {
    console.log(“I have a ball and cup.”);
} else if (ball > 0) {
    console.log(“I have a ball.”);
}
if (ball <= 0 && cup > 0) {
    console.log(“I have a cup”);
} else if (ball <= 0) {
    console.log(“I have nothing”);
}
```

Instead of nesting `if-else` statements, you can just check for multiple conditions in each `if` statement.